# Device Groups and Topics Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I currently make Firebase Device Groups and it works until a user logs out (or clears their memory and logs into another account). In that case, the user gets messages from their old group, and the new group. What seems to happen is the old group retains the token to the device (even if it clears, so it updates automatically?).

As an example, if I am logged into an account, and then clear the app on the device and log back into another account, any FCM message sent to the new group is also sent to the old.. I've even tried to manually remove the individual device token from the old group to remove it, but it is invalid.

How can I remove users when they clear or uninstall the app? I can just remove on logout, but not sure what to do in these other cases...

If I use a topic, would it automatically remove people if they clear or uninstall?

Comment: Clearing the data of an app should invalidate the token. The next time the app runs it will generate a new token. Assuming that the new token is not part of the old device group then sending to the old device group should not result in the app receiving the message since the token is invalidated. Please confirm that the new token is not being added to the old device group.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete InstanceId when you logout and get new token

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
                FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```